# Match values in different lines using awk

Tags: awk

My file looks like the following example:

```
8  1
8  2
17 4
17 5
17 2
19 1
19 4
19 3
19 11
```

and I want to match the first column (have the same value) and make summation for the second column using awk, such as the following.

the result will be

```
8 3
17 11
19 19
```

and so on.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '$2>0{sum[$1]+=$2} END{for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]}}' input | sort -n
8 3
17 11
19 19
```

#### Implementation notes:

- As `awk` reads each line from the file, the command `$2>0{sum[$1]+=$2}` causes the partial sums to be saved.
- After the file is read, the command `END{for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]}}` prints out the results.
- Because awk's arrays are unordered, the output of `awk` is fed to `sort -n` to produce visually pleasing sorted output.

#### Nicer formating

To produce output with right-justified columns, use `printf` in place of `print`:

```
$ awk '$2>0{sum[$1]+=$2} END{for (i in sum) {printf "%3s%3s\n",i,sum[i]}}' input | sort -n
  8  3
 17 11
 19 19
```